# ios build size is bigger on device

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build, size

After reading other questions here, still, no solution found, I'm ok with the size of my textures and no need to compress anymore-
1. Why does it show Complete build size - 1112.5 mb 
while my textures are only 329.7 mb (on other questions here they say it won't affect the final size on the device, but it's not my case- )
2. When building on the device, I can check the phone storage and see that
the app takes 732MB, how come??

I feel like Unity/Xcode builds a lot of extra junk

Here is my build report- Unity 2018.3.9f1

```
Textures 329.7 mb 74.9% 
Meshes 3.3 mb 0.8% 
Animations 4.2 mb 0.9% 
Sounds 5.0 mb 1.1% 
Shaders 2.4 mb 0.5% 
Other Assets 73.7 mb 16.7% 
Levels 17.6 mb 4.0% 
Scripts 626.3 kb 0.1% 
Included DLLs 2.9 mb 0.7% 
File headers 1.0 mb 0.2% 
Total User Assets 440.4 mb 100.0% 
Complete build size 1112.5 mb
```

size on iphone- 732MB

Comment: Please go with this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277230/same-app-version-but-different-size-on-iphones-on-testflight.

Answer (score 0):

1. Complete build size means the unzip size(1112.5MB), iOS *.ipa file is a zip file in fact(732MB).
2. Beside Unity Assets, the IL2CPP Code can take a lot space, you can reduce by only supporting ARM64. Other tricks like reduce C# Generic and Struct-Array.